# differential amplifier will cancel DC present at input

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, amplifier, signal, differential

In differential amplifier, it is written that "only AC signal will be amplified and DC part at the input will be canceled and hence there is no need of DC blocking capacitor". I am not getting this concept. According to me DC signal at the input should also amplify. Please explain.

Comment: If both inputs have the same DC bias, subtracting them will cancel them out, only the signal difference will remain.

Answer (score 2):

A differential amplifier will amplify a differential DC signal just as well as it amplifies a differential AC signal.

Similarly, it will have very little, if any, gain for common-mode signals, whether they are DC or AC.

If your source was somehow implying that DC signals are always common-mode, and that AC signals are differential, then the statement is sort of true, but it's conflating two completely separate issues, which makes it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amplifier but, in the strictest sense, with perfect, ideal amplifiers, if both inputs have the same dc offset then there will be no dc content on the output. What you appear to be deducing is that a differential amplifier only amplifies an AC signal and ignores a DC difference - this is untrue.